# What do you call a fraction that cannot be written as a finite decimal?

Tags: numbers, mathematics, fractions

For example, the fraction ⅓ cannot be written, because it repeats infinitely (0.33333333... etc). Is there a particular word for numbers that cannot be written directly, but must be expressed as fractions?

Comment: They're called rational numbers with nonterminating decimal expansions.

Comment: And what of *irrational numbers*, those with non-terminating but non-repeating decimal representations ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I think those are disqualified by "must be expressed as fractions" since irrational numbers can't be expressed that way (at least using integers).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yes, I meant to exclude irrational numbers, as I feel they are a separate category.

Comment: I know what you meant, but in fact these numbers do not *have to be* expressed as fractions. For example, "0.333..." is just as precise as "1/3". The dots tell you that it repeats.

Comment: @Rupe No, you're just being pedantic. You're right that they don't have to be expressed as fractions; Technically, you can even express them as bananas if you want, given an appropriate translation from math into fruit. That misses the point of the question though.

Comment: This is a question of Math, not English.

Comment: @Benubird To be fair, on reflection, I guess I may be interpreting "finite decimal" a little strictly. I think of decimal notation as including a recurring symbol, and of the representations that include them as finite. That seems a very natural interpretation to me but I can see it's not a necessary one. So you're right, pedantic :)

Comment: Decimals ARE fractions. There are various ways to represent fractions: as decimals (decimal fractions), common (vulgar) fractions, percentages, parts per mil. If you're talking about more than one representation, it's essential to disambiguate.

Comment: Recurring decimals

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's getting into, as Oldcat says, math rather than english - in common parlance, "fractions" can mean both a fractional number, however expressed, and also the specific form of expressing it when one number is written over another, with a line between them. Although I suppose this might be a slang usage which is not common where you live, in which case I apologize, and should have explained that in my question.

Comment: Maths (sorry, math) rather than English? M-W has as its first defined sense: a :  a numerical representation (as 3⁄4, 5⁄8, or 3.234) indicating the quotient of two numbers.>> Though I'd say even this isn't accurate enough; ...'essentially indicating the quotient of two integers' is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also [Periodic decimal](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/periodic+decimal):

> Richard Suchenwirth 2002-04-27 - Periodic decimal fractions are numbers where a sequence of digits behind the decimal point (the period) is endlessly repeated,

for example:

1/7 = 0.142857142857..
 1/3 = 0.3333..

*Repeating decimal*  appears to be the most common definition according to : [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=periodic%20decimal%2Crecurring%20decimal%2Crepeating%20decimal&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cperiodic%20decimal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecurring%20decimal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crepeating%20decimal%3B%2Cc0)

Source:http://wiki.tcl.tk/3310

Comment: Best answer for being the only one to include all three answers: periodic, repeating, recurring. The Ngram is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean a **recurring decimal**?

> A decimal number that has digits that repeat forever.
>
> [[Math is Fun]](http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/recurring-decimal.html)

Comment: Also [*repeating* decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal).

Answer (score 1):

Is there a word for numbers that can be expressed as fractions but not as finite decimals? Not exactly.

There is a word for numbers that *cannot* be expressed as fractions; they are called **irrational numbers.**

Any number that *can* be expressed as a fraction is a **rational number**. However, this term encompasses both numbers like 1/3 that have repeating decimal representations, and numbers like 1/2 that don't.

Any number that, like 1/3, has a decimal number that repeats endlessly, is called a **repeating decimal** or **recurring decimal.**

There are also numbers like pi and e that have decimal portions that neither terminate nor repeat. I believe, however, that these numbers are always irrational, meaning they cannot be represented as fractions.

If that is the case--and I welcome corrections from any mathematicians slumming on the ELL board--then all of the numbers you refer to would be repeating/recurring decimal numbers.

Comment: When we say 'Any number that can be expressed as a [common] fraction is a rational number', we're conveniently assuming that, if a/b is the simplest form, the integers a and b are not so large that we'll not live long enough to write them .

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Any number X can be expressed as a fraction: X/1. I think the ability to write the number is not the main assumption being made when we call something rational.

Comment: @Benubird 'We'? I was a maths teacher. But this is an English usage site. The modal 'can' carries different senses / nuances, and I was disambiguating. In mathsspeak, I'd use 'a rational is a number that can be expressed in the form a/b where a and b are integers' without worrying about the implications of 'can'. But the mathematical register is largely OT here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I find it interesting that in the discussion on this topic I find no reference to 'vulgar fraction', which is what they were called when I was at school. Has the name been discontinued to suppress titters of laughter in classrooms?

Comment: @WS2 The usual denotation of 'vulgar' ([1] lacking sophistication or good taste; unrefined.
"the vulgar trappings of wealth"
synonyms: tasteless, crass, tawdry, ostentatious, flamboyant, overdone, showy, gaudy, garish, brassy, kitsch, [Google]) surely makes the less baggagey 'common' (which is equally at home in the 'usual' and 'tawdrey / vulgar' senses) the better choice. We used to have a slight laugh with 'vulgar fractions'; it's only right to point out an acceptable usage, but also that it is quite a rare one nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

"Periodic decimal" is actually a name for a representation of such numbers, just as vulgar fraction is a name for the representation `p/q`.

One could call the numbers themselves:

- Numbers which have a periodic decimal representation.
- Rationals which in their simplest form `p/q`, `q` has a factor other than 2 or 5.

This is another way of saying that the numbers themselves do not really have a name used by mathematicians. The reason for this is that the decimal representation is not usually considered particularly special.

One can for example represent ⅓ in ternary exactly as `0.1`.